# Extrapolate with groups by another column

Tags: r

I have a bunch of time series data and I want to apply the percentage change from one to the end of another, groupwise. I have a simplified example below, but I have to do this for hundreds of time series pairs.

This is my best attempt so far, but it only calculates one value and the rest are `NA`'s

```
dplyr::mutate(dummydata, newtimeseries = ifelse(date > date_to_start_interp, dplyr::lag(value_to_interp, 1) * (value_to_use/ dplyr::lag(value_to_use, 1)), value_to_interp))
```

**Variables:** 
`category`: A grouping variable for the set of observations 
`date`: The date of the observations 
`value_to_interp`: The values that need extrapolating 
`value_to_use`: The values that I want to use to extrapolate (again, using the period to period percent change) 
`date_to_start_interp`: The date that I want the extrapolation to begin (NOTE: in some cases I want to overwrite data in the value_to_interp column, so this date is important)

**Data:**

```
dummydata <- structure(list(category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(14610, 
14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 
14914, 14944, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 
14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944), class = "Date"), value_to_interp = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, NA, NA, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 18, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), value_to_use = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 
40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 100, 95, 105, 90, 110, 85, 115, 80, 120, 
75, 125, 70), date_to_start_interp = structure(c(14914, 14914, 
14914, 14914, 14914, 14914, 14914, 14914, 14914, 14914, 14914, 
14914, 14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 
14761, 14761, 14761, 14761), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


#DESIRED OUTCOME

dummydata_desiredoutcome <- structure(list(category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(14610, 
14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 
14914, 14944, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 
14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944), class = "Date"), value_to_interp = c(10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20.9, 22.8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
3.863636364, 5.227272727, 3.636363636, 5.454545455, 3.409090909, 
5.681818182, 3.181818182), value_to_use = c(5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 
25L, 30L, 35L, 40L, 45L, 50L, 55L, 60L, 100L, 95L, 105L, 90L, 
110L, 85L, 115L, 80L, 120L, 75L, 125L, 70L), date_to_start_interp = structure(c(14914, 
14914, 14914, 14914, 14914, 14914, 14914, 14914, 14914, 14914, 
14914, 14914, 14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 
14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 14761), class = "Date")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is almost certainly a better way of doing this, but I created a separate df that filtered out the observations that needed extrapolating:

`dummydata_extrapolateforward <- dplyr::filter(dummydata, date >= date_to_start_interp)`

Because I used `>=` in the `filter` above, I had a bunch of groups with one observation that I wanted to extrapolate using a bunch of other observations.

So, I used the `first()` and `last()` functions from `dplyr` to create a cumulative percent change calculation that then gets applied to that first observation.

`dplyr::mutate(value_to_interp = dplyr::first(value_to_interp) * value_to_use / dplyr::first(value_to_use))`

Then I just did another `filter()` to get those same observations out of the main `df` and did an `rbind()` to recombine.

Again, definitely a terrible way of solving this problem and I am definitely still open to learning a better way.

TL;DR: `dplyr()` has a function called `first()` that you can use to find the first observation of each group. Once you have that, you can calculate a cumulative percent change from the data you are using to extrapolate and apply that to the data point that you want extrapolated.